# Can you connect in series 2 unequally charged batteries?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, low-battery

So I have 4 batteries. 2 of them are charged (about 70%) and 2 about 10%. I have a flashlight (which uses 2 batteries in **series**) which I would like to power at small current and voltage because the light produced is too powerful. Would combining a charged battery and discharged battery be a good idea? If not, what can I do? I thought of placing a piece of iron where the discharged battery would be so it conducts the current from the first one. Would that work?
**Note that they are single use batteries.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, is your flashlight an LED? Or incandescent?

Comment: Surely not LED.

Comment: Just bypass the second cell then. Reducing the voltage will reduce the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bad idea. Besides the fact that it says not to do this on the battery package, here is the reason:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdATqB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, the batteries that are used have a lower cell voltage, but also a higher internal resistance. They aren't contributing much to the power delivery, and they will dissipate quite a lot in heat! This will eventually rupture the battery.

Your bypass might work if the circuit is capable of using a lower voltage, and the batteries you use are capable of delivering a higher current to compensate for the reduced voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Would be putting a 70% cell in series with a 10% cell be a good idea?

No. Once they are down to 60% and 0%, the battery at the end of its life will have its terminal vpltage collapse, and get reverse biassed. Not that this matters much to a single use battery, you were going to throw it away anyway, but it won't light the torch.

Two discharged batteries in series, or one well charged cell in series with a conductor would work better.

Have you considered using a bulb with a suitable design voltage for your batteries?

Comment: Even with single-use batteries, reverse biasing greatly increases the possibility of "venting" (i.e. spewing goo).  Even if a dead battery would have no value, that doesn't mean there's no harm in damaging it further.